# getting animation to run multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have this animation that I want to be able to run multiple times. Here is what I currently have: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/c5ekkqxf/1/). I want to be able to make the "done" thing appear every time I press the button. I tried adding something like this:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('#divProcessing').addClass('show');
    $('#divProcessing').removeClass('hidden');
}, 1000);
```

But that makes the animation "reverse" which I dont want. ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/c5ekkqxf/2/)).

Comment: That's not really logical CSS rule: `.show {
    visibility:hidden;
}`

Comment: @A.Wolff ok. So how should I go about doing this? =) I'm really lost here :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick
http://jsfiddle.net/txqs3m6L/

What was done here, was introduction of another css class "animate":

```
.animate {
    transition: all 500ms linear;    
}
```

which gets removed after animation is over, to ensure that the popup is not animated back and is reset silently.

The transition part got removed from the basic div object.

As for the click action, your approach was correct.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You should use `tansitionend` event instead of a timeout, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/c5ekkqxf/8/